# Text chat using php ajax, resending failed message

Tags: php, ajax, chat, pusher

We want to create a text chat using pusher notification, php and ajax. Following sql will create table for text chat messages.

```
CREATE TABLE `text_chat_messages` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `user_random_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,   `user_full_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `message` text,   `received` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `timestamp` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
```

**What I want is to have following features.**

- Send a message to user
- If message is received that message will be marked as sent meaning received = 1
- Any message that is not sent will be sent again after 4 seconds I am using ajax/php polling for this
- User's full name is being saved this will be used in resend message
- I am polling page every 10 seconds to check for messages that weren't received and resend those messages

**Problems**

- I want to resend messages that are not received again but to same user as they are intend to I mean if User A and User B are chatting and message is not received by User B that message should not go to User C
- How do I updated received field to 1 as soon as message sent by User A is received by User B I mean how do I check which message is received so that message's received field is updated in database.
- How do I send messages in order for example if one message fails and message after that is received whole sequence of chat will be broken. One solution for this will be to stop all messages after one message fails but how to achieve this.

Also I would appreciate any further ideas on this I am sure there are lots of things still missing.
We also want to use utf8 for our chat system so if you can give me any ideas on that as well that will be helpful.

This probably is lots of questions in one question but I want to make this chat work so this handles all basic features of chat and also chat is saved in database so users can see chat history.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. If you store inside that entry to your database to what user that message is intended to be sent, then why is it an issue afterwards to retrieve that information? Why should it get sent to some other account?

Comment: "lots of things still missing" are things we cannot help with, sorry.

Comment: Apart from that - what is that "ajax/php polling" after 4 seconds for and why "polling" at all if you use push notifications? Why two (three?) different mechanisms here?

Comment: I am storing user id of user that is sending message so that user can see his chat history, I can save user id of second user for whom message is intended but pusher handles that part I have no access to that information in advance.

Comment: I am quite certain that service does allow to control to what user a message is sent...

Comment: @arkascha here is the problem, User A sends a message and Internet fails at User B's end then message is sent but not received by User B pusher doesn't handles this part because User B never received that event to their pusher channel

Comment: @arkascha no it doesn't message is sent to a channel through an event any number of users can be subscribed to that channel

Comment: Ah, you send to a group of users, you do not mention that in your question.